# How to visit a webpage using PuTTY?

Tags: aws, vps, putty

I'm using Ubuntu VPS server, and I want to do a simple thing.
I want to go to a webpage through the terminal to do a couple of checks regarding my website's traffic.
I just need it to open a browser (not visually of course), go to a URL, and that's it.
How do I do that guys?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  You could try using a text web browser (eg. `lynx` or `w3m`)  but I'm not sure this is what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

For use webpage on the terminal, you can use below commands

1) **elinks** http://example.com
2) **curl** http://example.com

above both commands, you have to install first.

Comment: what is the command for installing those?

Comment: For centos, You can use this commands"yum install elinks curl -y"
For Ubuntu, You can use this commands "apt-get install elinks curl -y"

Comment: And why would you be giving commands for CentOS on an Ubuntu site.

Comment: For knowledge purpose

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options to download a website as your remote server that you have SSHed into:

**Text-mode web browser**

These run in the terminal and will render text (but generally not images or script). Options include: `elinks`, `links`, `links2`, and `lynx`. You can install with, for example, `sudo apt update && sudo apt install elinks`

**Command line tool**

Tools that allow you to download a webpage on the command line include `curl`, `wget`, and `Python` with the `requests` library. Example using `curl`:

```
curl localhost

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
html { color-scheme: light dark; }
body { width: 35em; margin: 0 auto;
font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
<p>If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and
working. Further configuration is required.</p>

<p>For online documentation and support please refer to
<a href="http://nginx.org/">nginx.org</a>.<br/>
Commercial support is available at
<a href="http://nginx.com/">nginx.com</a>.</p>

<p><em>Thank you for using nginx.</em></p>
</body>
</html>
```

**SOCKS proxy**

You could route your desktop browser's internet connection through your SSH connection. Instructions are available in multiple places on the net (including https://ioflood.com/blog/how-to-use-putty-as-a-socks-proxy-a-step-by-step-guide/). This is a bit more involved but allows you to use a full GUI based browser but with the connection as if you're on the server.

**VPN connection**

A Wireguard VPN is relatively straightforward to set up and will give you a connection as if you're on the server. This is outside the scope of this question as you've specifically asked about SSH/PuTTY.